# PHP - passing unknown/large string values to script

Tags: php, url, variables

I have a php script (listening.php) listening for any in-bound `GET` requests.

For now, I only listen for specific `GET` variables. All other variables are ignored.

I'm placing a simple pixel-type script on an outside url:

```
<?php
 $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
?>
<script src="http://mydomain.com/listening.php?page=1&url=<?php echo $url;?>"></script>
```

This works fine and dandy.
I'd like to pass more info, but I'd like to pass all `$_SERVER` variables in the array.

I have a few options, like looping through the array, and building the url string with the key/values.

But, I'm more interested in passing the entire array as a whole, and storing it in mysql, inside a Text column.

I know there's probably a limit of how large a single string can be passed via a url.

Does anyone have a good way or idea on a best practice for doing this?
Personally I expect passing an array via the url is not a good idea, but I'm fishing for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encode and serialize the array:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'];
$srv = base64_encode(serialize($_SERVER));
?>
<script src="http://mydomain.com/listening.php?page=1&url=<?php echo $url;?>&srv=<?php echo $srv; ?>"></script>
```

Then in the listening script, you do the reverse:

```
<?php
$srv = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['srv']));
?>
```

However, keep in mind that these requests have a limitation on GET length.

With that said, you could use `gzcompress` and `gzuncompress`:

```
$srv = base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($_SERVER)));
```

Uncompress it:

```
<?php
$srv = unserialize(base64_decode(gzuncompress($_GET['srv'])));
?>
```

Comment: I did a test and it looks like `gzdeflate` and `gzinflate` may be viable options as well.

Comment: I like your optimized form of encoding and serializing the array. I hadn't thought of this, and seems the most viable route.

Comment: Based off of some research, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request , it seems you *might* be OK to use this. You may want to select what you want from `$_SERVER` just to shorten the length of the string.. However, in my testing, $srv ended up only being around 1200 characters including the compression.